# Maximum weight forest?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees

If I have a graph and I need to find a maximum weight forest, but because a graph is already a forest, is it enough to find the maximum spanning tree?

thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forest is just an acyclic graph (not necessarily connected, but its connected components are trees).  To find a maximum weight forest for a graph, you can find a maximum weight forest on each of its connected components.  If there are negative weights, the resulting forest need not be spanning.

Comment: on each of its connecting components? do you mean that I have to find all max trees that combined include all of the original forests edges and nodes?

Comment: No, I mean that the problem decomposes by connected component.  The resulting maximum weighted forest will be a subset of the original graph and need not contain all nodes or all edges.

Comment: So by saying I can find a maximum weight forest on each of its connected components, which are trees, I need to find the max weight tree, right?

Comment: No, if there are negative weights, a maximum forest of a tree need not be connected.

Comment: but if there are no negative weights?

Comment: If all weights are nonnegative, then at least one maximum weight forest of a connected graph is a maximum weight spanning tree.

Comment: thank you very much